# Concatenating datasets of different RDDs in Apache spark using scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, distributed-computing, rdd

Is there a way to concatenate datasets of two different `RDD`s in spark?

Requirement is - I create two intermediate RDDs using scala which has same column names, need to combine these results of both the RDDs and cache the result for accessing to UI. How do I combine the datasets here?

RDDs are of type `spark.sql.SchemaRDD`

Comment: Can't you just use `++` ?

Comment: @lmm No.. It will add columns to the RDD. I need to add rows to the RDD. I have two RDDs with same columns whose records needs to be merged to a single RDD.

Comment: No it won't, I just tried it to be sure. `++` creates a union RDD with the results from both.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I think you are looking for `RDD.union`

```
val rddPart1 = ???
val rddPart2 = ???
val rddAll = rddPart1.union(rddPart2)
```

Example (on Spark-shell)

```
val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(Seq((1, "Aug", 30),(1, "Sep", 31),(2, "Aug", 15),(2, "Sep", 10)))
val rdd2 = sc.parallelize(Seq((1, "Oct", 10),(1, "Nov", 12),(2, "Oct", 5),(2, "Nov", 15)))
rdd1.union(rdd2).collect

res0: Array[(Int, String, Int)] = Array((1,Aug,30), (1,Sep,31), (2,Aug,15), (2,Sep,10), (1,Oct,10), (1,Nov,12), (2,Oct,5), (2,Nov,15))
```

Comment: rddPart1.union(rddPart2) will add columns of rddPart2 to rddPart1. I need to add rows of rddPart2 to rddPart1. FYI, both the RDDs in this case have the same column names and types

Comment: It is more like inserting records into an already existing RDD. Not creating new columns to RDD

Comment: @example added an example. There're no new columns to an union RDD.

Comment: While the example makes it look like concatenation takes place (rdd1 is followed by rdd2 in the output), I don't believe `union` makes any guarantees about ordering of the data. They could get mixed up with each other. Real concatenation is not so easy, because it implies an order dependency in your data, which is fighting against distributed-ness of spark.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. To combine by row instead of column use unionAll:

```
val rddPart1= ???
val rddPart2= ???
val rddAll = rddPart1.unionAll(rddPart2)
```

I found it after reading the method summary for data frame. More information at: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html

Comment: Not sure it is the right answer, the question was about RDD, not how to do it with dataframes