# How to join two (or more) streams (JavaDStream) in apache spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming

We have a spark streaming application that consumes Gnip compliance stream.

In the old version of the API, the compliance stream was provided by one end point but now it is provided by 8 different endpoints.

We could run the same spark application 8 times with different parameters to consume different endpoints.

Is there a way in spark streaming to consume the 8 endpoints and merge them into one in the same application?

Should we use different streaming context for each connection or one context is enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for Spark [union](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD@union(other:org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[T]):org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[T]) here.

Read following for examples [Concatenating datasets of different RDDs in Apache spark using scala](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27395420/2784721)

As per Spark documentation Spark union :

> Return a new dataset that contains the union of the elements in the
>   source dataset and the argument.